# I have problem viewport in mobile with modal bootstrap?

Tags: mobile

plis

> `[Blockquote][1]`

[problem in mobile with boostrap and vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arx9F.jpg)

Comment: my page is greenpointcusco.com/carta/

Comment: It was 100% at 100vh if it works for someone